# Which to print first in a 2D Array?

Tags: arrays

I was told that there was a convention when you have a code to print an array, that there is a value that must come first than the other one, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; column++)
            System.out.print("" + array[i][j]);}
```

Would be `i` first or it needs to be `j` first? I find answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641985/which-comes-first-in-a-2d-array-rows-or-columns) but they don't solve my doubt...

PS: I'm not asking just about Java, but about C#, C, C++, Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention is to do it in order, as you have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; column++)
            System.out.print("" + array[i][j]);}
```

Here, `i` is before `j` in the loops, and `array` is indexed by `i` before `j` as well.

This is the natural order, as written in the code. It is also the order in which the memory elements are stored in most languages (Java, C#, C, C++). This is called row-major order, where elements in the same row are in contiguous memory locations.

For a 3 by 3 array `a[3][3]` in row-major order, the elements are stored as:

```
a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2], a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2], a[2][0], a[2][1], a[2][2]
```

Indexing into the array in row-major order also has performance benefits. By accessing memory sequentially, you minimise cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

means that `i` serves as an index for the elements of `array` (the elements happen to be sub arrays).

```
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; column++)
```

indicates that `j` serves as an index for the elements of `array[i]` (the sub arrays of `array`).

So yes, `i` needs to be before `j`.