# How to add all elements in a column of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to add all the elements in a column of a two-dimensional array with differently-lengthed arrays. I'm almost there, but I can't figure out why the program is suddenly doing things seemingly against what the code is directing. Obviously it's only doing what the code tells it to, but I can't discern exactly what and why. Help is appreciated.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                         {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                         {9, 1, 0, 2},
                         {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };
        
        int total = 0;
        int tick = 4;
        int row = 0;
        
        for (int col = 0; col != 5; col++) {
            for (int num = 0; num < data.length; num++) {
                if (col != 0 && data[row].length<col+1){
                    row++; //checks to see whether or not the column
                           // num is in range of the subarray
                }
                
                total += data[row][col];
                
                if (row == tick-1) {
                    System.out.println(total);
                }
                row++;
                
                if (row == tick) { //stops row from going over max
                    row = 0;
                    total = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why iterate over all columns?  The column of interest should be a fixed value for whichever column to sum, and only need to iterate over the rows.  (Along with checking the length of the current row does not exceed the column of interest.)  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641985/which-comes-first-in-a-2d-array-rows-or-columns) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in your logic of skipping rows which have fewer columns then the current column number.

In the 5th iteration when `col = 4` the row skip is working like this

```
Iteration for the inner for loop when col 4
num goes from 0 .. 3

Iteration 1 (num = 0)
[row = 0]
Row 0 : Size [3] Skip by doing row++
[row = 1]
Do logic of adding number from Row 1 into total, row++
[row = 2]

Iteration 2 (num = 1)
[row = 2]
Row 2 : Size [4] Skip by doing row++
[row = 3]
Do logic of adding number from Row 3 into total, row++
[row = 4]
Logic to reset row and total get triggered resetting both to 0
```

As you can see that you tick rest happens in the second iteration itself and the inner loop then runs 2 more times adding back wrong values into your total.

A better way to do this would be to maintain an output array which holds the column wise sums

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception {
    int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                     {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                     {9, 1, 0, 2},
                     {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };

    ArrayList<Integer> columnWiseSum = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.length; rowIndex++) {
      int[] row = data[rowIndex];
      for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.length; colIndex++) {
        // Insert a column into the output list if it does not exist
        if (columnWiseSum.size() - 1 < colIndex) {
          columnWiseSum.add(0);
        }

        int cellValue = data[rowIndex][colIndex];
        
        // Add the value of this cell into the output
        columnWiseSum.set(colIndex, columnWiseSum.get(colIndex) + cellValue);
      }
    }

    System.out.println(columnWiseSum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop had the condition `col != 5`, which meant that the outer loop would run as long as col isn't equal to `5`. This condition assumed that there were always `5` columns in the two-dimensional array, which may not be the case when subarrays have different lengths.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm looking for a way to add all the elements in a column of a two-dimensional array with differently-lengthed arrays. ..."*

This type of *array* is commonly referred to as a, *"[jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)"*.

Here is an example.
Iterate on *data*, checking each *sub-array* for an *n<sup>th</sup>* element, and increment *x* when applicable.

This will return *−8*, when *n* is *5*, and *12*, when *n* is *4*.

```java
int columnSum(int n, int[][] data) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int[] a : data) if (n < a.length) x += a[n];
    return x;
}
```

Or, use a *[stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

```java
int columnSum(int n, int[][] data) {
    return Stream.of(data)
                 .filter(x -> n < x.length)
                 .mapToInt(x -> x[n])
                 .sum();
}
```

> *"... I'm almost there, but I can't figure out why the program is suddenly doing things seemingly against what the code is directing. ..."*

The effort is valid, typically a *double loop* is used to traverse *2-dimensional arrays*.
Although, in this situation you're only accessing a single dimension, technically, so use a single *loop*.